Bug in WSO2apim Provider
I'm using the terraform WSO2 provider to create APIs in WSO2, but I got a 404 error. Because, provider was hitting the wrong endpoint instead of correct one. Also tried with curl, which also failed to reach the correct URL.
The wso2 installation is complete, and the API is also created via terraform which I can see on the UI, but still I'm getting the same error.
It seems there's a bug within the provider itself. To make sure, that this error lies within the provider only, I've verified it by installing other versions of wso2, but I'm still facing the same issue. I also verified the wso2 URL and authentication details, which seem correct configurations. Is there any other way to do this?
WSO2 Provider- Terraform wso2 provider
Error
Does anyone know how to resolve this error?
Tested versions of wso2- 4.3.0 & 3.2.0.
When using Terraform to create an API, getting an unsuccessful api call error. I've tried creating the API manually using curl, but got HTML response instead of JSON is returned with 200 OK status, which seems to indicate I'm being directed to the wrong endpoint.
Has anyone faced a similar issue with the WSO2 terraform provider? Could this be a bug in the provider itself?
